# STACK storage, laravel 5.1 and webdav get images from folder and display them all

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, webdav, flysystem

I'm trying to store and receive images from my STACK storage (on a raid server rack). It's designed to store files (especially images for me).

So I'm using the plugin 'Flysystem' and the Webdav plugin what comes with it.

Now, The code I'm using to get a single file is this:

```
public function GetImagesFromFolder($folder)
{
    return Flysystem::listContents("TAC-Tielt-2013");
    die;
    $filename = basename('logo_small.png');
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

    switch($file_extension) {
        case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
        default:
    }

    return response(Flysystem::read('logo_small.png'))->header('Content-Type', $ctype);
}
```

The only problem here, is that I need to get all the files from a specific folder... However, this doesn't work at all.

Here is my STACK structure:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/5b91d71e5c3444f0a0e53c1ec4dcdd49.png
http://image.prntscr.com/image/fce1dc7f450c42758c7eef98b109a95e.png

How am I suppose to get everything from this? I kinda want to be able to list the folders inside of the 'root' of my storage and then also when a specific url is requested (the folder name), that it displays all the images. How can I do this?